# Translation of submit_tag and usage in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The rails form helper `submit_tag` adds an input whose name is"commit" and whose value is the value of the input.

I have a form with multiple submit buttons, and I was thinking of using the trick of `params[:commit]` to decide which action should be performed in the controller.

Problem is, translations. This button needs to be translated, and the original value of the commit is lost. How do I deal with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a button tag like this:

```
<button name="commit" value="some_value">some_translated_text</button>
```

A button will behave the same as an input tag when used in a form. See:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5